# Sum of values in a foreach loop php

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have a response like this:

```
  "data": [
            {

                "pay": "2010000",

            },
            {

                "pay": "3010000",

            },
            {

                "pay": "3920000",

            },
]

    foreach ($data as $data) {
              $sum += $data['pay'];

              array_push($newArr, array(
                        "finalResult" => '0',
                     )
                    );
            }
```

I want to get (individual pay divided by sum of all pay) results  and should push this value into array.  I have a foreach loop where I'm trying to get the final result. But the final result array is showing incorrect data. Is there anything I'm missing?

I tried this with two foreach loops like this. But I'm getting wrong result

```
foreach ($newArr as $newArr_key => $newArr_value) {

            if ($sum != 0) {
                $finalResult = $data['pay']/ $sum;


                if (isset($finalResult) && $finalResult != '') {
                    $newArr[$newArr_key]['finalResult'] = $finalResult;
                }

            } else {
                $finalResult = 'Division by Zero';
            }


            }
```

Comment: This is not duplicate of the question you linked.

Comment: what is the final result array?

Comment: "finalResult" : $finalResult

Comment: The input data you show is neither a correct json nor an array also. Please correct your input data first and then ask question

Comment: You don't divide by sum of **all** pay. You divide be the sum of payments your loop processed until then. You can fix it with two foreach loops.

Comment: @yer if that is how your code is laid out, it seems that you're not closing the `data` JSON, nor are you closing the `array_push`.

Comment: Can you please correct the syntax errors in your question to create a [mcve]? I think I see the real problem, but it's difficult to address it with so many other problems in the way.

Comment: @jh1711 I tried with two foreach loops. I edited the answer. Please check and see if I'm missing anything

Comment: _"is showing incorrect data"_ -> after correcting the syntax I tested the 'function and it shows correct data. If you put `1,1,1` as your pay values it gives you `1, 0.5, 0,3333333` - which is 1/1, 1/2, 1/3. But the way you decode the json and what $data is initially (you have it twice!?) might be crucial

Comment: @AlivetoDie I entered. Please Check

Comment: for me it's working as expected: [gist](https://gist.github.com/jeffstagedoor/e9e11f6026c191a48dbbae699d7ccc7f) (I couldn't find a php fiddle that I could share..)

Comment: @Jeff I'm getting the same values for example: finalResult: 0.5,0.5,0.5

Comment: found one: https://3v4l.org/iHINN

Comment: then there must be different in you code that I don't see...

Comment: What is the desired output please?

Comment: An array with finalResult : individual pay / total pay

Comment: Basically the percentage each pay is of the sum of pay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`array_sum()`](https://php.net/array_sum) with [`array_column()`](https://php.net/array_column) to compute the total sum of "pay".
Then you could use [`array_map()`](https://php.net/array_map) to compute the average of individual sum along the total sum.

```
$data = [
    ["pay" => "2010000"],
    ["pay" => "3010000"],
    ["pay" => "3920000"],
];
$sum = array_sum(array_column($data, 'pay'));
$out = array_map(function($item) use($sum) {
    return ['finalResult' => $item['pay'] / $sum] ;
}, $data);
print_r($out);
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [finalResult] => 0.2248322147651
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [finalResult] => 0.33668903803132
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [finalResult] => 0.43847874720358
        )

)
```

Or :

```
$data = [
    ["pay" => "2010000"],
    ["pay" => "3010000"],
    ["pay" => "3920000"],
];
$sum = array_sum(array_column($data, 'pay'));
$out = array_map(function($item) use($sum) {
    return $item['pay'] / $sum ;
}, $data);
print_r($out);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0.2248322147651
    [1] => 0.33668903803132
    [2] => 0.43847874720358
)
```

Comment: Thank you @Jeff. Yer, don't forget to post an example of the desired output for your future questions to help answerers to understand what you really want. Thank you :)